# undefined method `id' for "2":String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is probably a simple problem. I'm attempting to update a user instance's sex via a form select but am running into issues. Here are the relevant models:

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  . . .

  has_one :user_sex
  has_one :sex, :through => :user_sex

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_sex
end
```

sex.rb

```
class Sex < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum options: [:"Not Known", :"Male", :"Female", :"Not Applicable"]
  has_one :user_sex
  has_one :user, :through => :user_sex
end
```

user_sex.rb

```
class UserSex < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :sex
end
```

This is the relevant piece of my template:

edit.html.erb

```
. . .

<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :sex %><br />
  <%= f.select :sex, Sex.options, :class => "form-control" %>
  <%= showErrorMessages("Sex", :sex) %>
</div>

. . .
```

Here's the HTML output from my select code:

```
<select id="user_sex" name="user[sex]">
  <option value="0">Not Known</option>
  <option value="1">Male</option>
  <option value="2">Female</option>
  <option value="3">Not Applicable</option>
</select>
```

When I submit the form, I receive an error that reads "undefined method `id' for "2":String" and then see more error-related messaging (see attached image). Does anyone know how I can fix this?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the way you're declaring your enum (probably belongs directly in the user unless you want them to have multiple sexes that you're tracking over time?). Try the following:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum sex: { unknown: 0, male: 1, female: 2, n_a: 3 }
end
```

Then simply set the default of 0 in your DB and assign as expected.

If you want to add sex to multiple classes, I suggest using `ActiveSupport::Concern`, like this:

```
#app/models/concerns/sex.rb
module Sex
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    enum sex: { unknown: 0, male: 1, female: 2, n_a: 3 }
  end
end

# app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Sex
end
```

Comment: Your solution makes sense. Do you think I may be overthinking this? I should mention that I'm making sex its own table because other entities within my app may have a sex. It seems reasonable to me to store the possible values for sex within the database.

Comment: In that case I'd create a concern that you an reuse for each of the models that you're looking to add sex to. I'll update my answer for that.

Comment: What I'm not understanding so far is how to access the enum I've defined within my concern from the view. I've not seen code samples describing this, either. I would image that, in my case, it would look something like <%= User.sex %>, but this isn't working.

Comment: Your enum acts like a mapping for the available values. In your case you could leave your view as it stands (you're assigning a value 0-4 to user.sex). You can then perform checks in your backend via the mapped symbols, e.g. `user.male?`, which are being stored in your db by their numeric values.